# IE9/10 quotes in Yii menu item linkOptions->onclick being encoded as &quot

Tags: internet-explorer, yii, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

In IE9/10, Yii menu item

```
$this->menu=array(
...
array('label'=>'Project Report', 'url'=>'#',
    'linkOptions'=>array('onclick'=>'$("#projectDatePicker").dialog("open");$(".hidden-dialog").removeAttr("style"); return false;')),
...
?>
```

is being rendered as,

```
<a onclick="$(&quot;#projectDatePicker&quot;).dialog(&quot;open&quot;);$(&quot;.hidden-dialog&quot;).removeAttr(&quot;style&quot;); return false;"
```

In IE9/10 on the first render, and it will work after refreshing the page. This does not appear to be a problem in any other IE versions but IE9/10, any ideas?

Comment: did u tried prefixing the javascript with `js:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do it either. My workaround:

```
$this->menu=array(
...
array('label'=>'Project Report', 'url'=>'#',
    'linkOptions'=>array('onclick'=>'openDialog()')),
...
?>

<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('open-dialog', '
    function openDialog() {
        $("#projectDatePicker").dialog("open");
        $(".hidden-dialog").removeAttr("style");
        return false;
    }
', CClientScript::POS_END); ?>
```